# When I try to navigate to https://website.com/index.php#section it just leads me to the index.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a website with a bunch of sections and I have a header and I want to go to a section from another page then if I use https://website.com/index.php#section it just leads me to the index.php

When I click on any link on the page itself to any section it goes to that section but when I directly put the link as https://website.com/index.php#section in the browser it doesn't work

```
<a href="#section">Go to section</a> 

<div id="section">
</div>
```

When I click on the link I go to the section but if I try to come here from a totally different webpage by using

```
<a href="https://website.com/index.php#section">Go to the Section on other page</a>
```

This won't work, it just takes me to index.php but won't scroll

NOTE - I noticed this on Microsoft Edge Chromium Version

Should I be adding separate code in javascript/jquery to scroll again?

Comment: Can you share more details?

Comment: Like I'm using the ids to link within sections of a page and when I click on any button o lead to the section it goes but when I directly type it as a webaddress in the url 

like website.com/index.php#section it just goes to the index file and stays there
doesn't scroll to the section with that id

Comment: Please share more details, and add them to your question by editing it (not to the comment section). What's the difference between these section links? Can you share sample code that triggers the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the id inside the tag.

Target where you need the link to respond:

```
<div id="section">The Section</div>
```

Link to the targeted div tag:

```
<a href="#section">Click me!</a>
```

What we did here is that we gave the div tag an id which will relocate the screen to itself (the div tag in this case) whenever it is called from somewhere else on the same screen.

Comment: yeah I did this but if I let's say redirecting from another website to this page and to this section I gotta use website.com/index.php#section right?

that doesn't scroll to the section it just goes to index and stays there

Answer (score 0):

You use an anchor and a hash. For example:

Target of the Link:

```
<div name="lable">Content foo bar</div>
```

Link to the Target:

```
 <a href="#lable">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: I did this....this is not my issue...please check the question again...I edited it to make it clear